# combinations without duplicates using php

Tags: php, math, combinations

I need all possible combinations in math sense (without duplicates) where n=30 and k=18

```
    function subcombi($arr, $arr_size, $count)
        {
           $combi_arr = array();
           if ($count > 1) {
              for ($i = $count - 1; $i < $arr_size; $i=$i+1) {
                 $highest_index_elem_arr = array($i => $arr[$i]);
                 foreach (subcombi($arr, $i, $count - 1) as $subcombi_arr) 
                 {
                     $combi_arr[] = $subcombi_arr + $highest_index_elem_arr;
                 }
              }
           } else {
              for ($i = $count - 1; $i < $arr_size; $i=$i+1) {
                 $combi_arr[] = array($i => $arr[$i]);
              }
           }

           return $combi_arr;
        }

        function combinations($arr, $count)
        {
           if ( !(0 <= $count && $count <= count($arr))) {
              return false;
           }


           return $count ? subcombi($arr, count($arr), $count) : array();
        } 

$numeri="01.02.03.04.05.06.07.08.09.10.11.12.13.14.15.16.17.18.19.20.21.22.23.24.25.26.27.28.29.30";

    $numeri_ar=explode(".",$numeri);  
    $numeri_ar=array_unique($numeri_ar);


    for ($combx = 2; $combx < 19; $combx++)
       {
    $combi_arr = combinations($numeri_ar, $combx);
    }

    print_r($combi_arr);
```

It works but it terminates with an out of memory error, of course, number of combinations is too large.

Now I do not need exactly all the combinations. I need only a few of them. 
I'll explain.

I need this work for a statistical study over Italian lotto. 
I have the lotto archive in this format saved in `$archivio` array

```
...
35.88.86.03.54
70.72.45.18.09
55.49.35.30.43
15.52.49.41.72
74.26.54.77.90
33.14.56.42.11
08.79.41.01.52
82.33.32.83.43
...
```

A full archive is available here
https://pastebin.com/tut6kFXf

newer extractions are on top.

I tried (unsuccessfully) to modify the function to do this

- for each 18 numbers combination found by the function combinations, the function should check if there are min. 3 numbers in one of the first 30 rows of `$archivio`. If "yes", the combination must not be saved in combination array, this combination has no statistical value for my need. If "no", the combination must be saved in combination array, this combination has great statistical value for my need.

In this way the total combinations will be no more than some hundred or thousand and I will avoid the out of memory and I'll have what I need.

The script time will be surely long but there should not be out of memory using the way above.

Anyone is able to help me in this ?
Thank you

Comment: Don't brute-force combinatronics. Use math.